# Prepared SMTP-data from SwiftMailer

Tags: php, symfony, email, phpmailer, swiftmailer

Can I get the prepared SMTP-data from swiftmailer message, like I can get it from PHPMailer when I am doing `PHPMailer::preSend()` and then `PHPMailer::getSentMIMEMessage()`

Comment: you mean like Message::toString()? https://github.com/symfony/mime/blob/master/Message.php#L106 / https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Message.php#L139

Comment: I am not sure that it is the same, what I get from PHPMailer::preSend() and then PHPMailer::getSentMIMEMessage()

Comment: neither am I, have you tried? it should have most of the headers though. maybe the getByteStream (swiftmailer) is better